# change image when I clicked on listview item

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make a media player app. In `listView` music exists. When I clicked one item, on right of the row, playing image seems. However, when I click an item, on non visible side of `listView`, another image also seems. I have searched a lot but iIcannot find any proper solution for me. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: What technology do you use?

Comment: Can you understand my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void createAnaTablo() {
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(
            MediaPlayerliClass.this, parcalar);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            p = position;
            sound_id = MediaPlayerliClass.this.getResources()
                    .getIdentifier(parcalar.get(position), "raw",
                            MediaPlayerliClass.this.getPackageName());
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
            if (prevView != null) {
                prevView.findViewById(R.id.simge).setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
            prevView = view;

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayerliClass.this, sound_id);
            mp.start();

            animation = new AnimationDrawable();
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equ1),
                    75);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equ2),
                    125);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equ3),
                    175);

            animation.setOneShot(false);

            view.findViewById(R.id.simge)
                    .setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

            // start the animation!
            animation.start();

            stop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            if (updateSeekBar.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
                updateSeekBar.start();
            }

            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                }
            });

        }

    });
}
```